# How was King Solomon's orders to kill adversaries sanctioned?

Tags: melachim-kings-book-of, king-solomon

Just reading Malachim and right into it there are killings ordered by Solomon via Banayah - including his own brother. How, tell me, please - is this sanctioned by Hashem and how does Hashem BLESS him afterward? Is there one set of laws for kings and another for the commoners? Because last time I checked it says - that shall not murder. And not one of these killings were in self-defense either, but seemingly revenge.

Answer (score 3):

The king has a right to kill anyone who rebels against him in any way or even slights him. As [Maimonides](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Kings_and_Wars.3.8?lang=en) writes this is learned from a verse in [Joshua](https://www.sefaria.org/Joshua.1.18?ven=The_Koren_Jerusalem_Bible&lang=en&with=Translations&lang2=en)

> The king has the right to execute anyone who rebels against a king. One is liable to the death penalty even if the king decreed that he is to go to a particular place and he did not go there or that he not leave his house and left. If he so wishes, he may execute him it says, “any man who disagrees with your words... shall be put to death.” (Joshua 1:18). Similarly, the king has permission to execute anyone who disgraces or embarrasses him or insults him, as was the case with Shimi ben Gera. The king has permission to execute only by the sword. He may imprison and beat someone with a whip for the sake of his honor. However, he may not declare their money ownerless, for it would be robbery were he to do so.

Comment: Who wrote that? Who made that law? Is that D'Oreita or was this the king's decree? What does the Torah say about killing? How does a king override Halacha?

Comment: Also the Mishneh Torah was written after Solomon's reign, what justification and law did he abide by if what you cite above was written after the fact?

Comment: Also, wasn't the building of the Beit Hamikdash taken out of David's hands because he had blood on them, so how does this not apply to Solomon?

Comment: I quoted Maimonides just because he is the most quotable. The source for the law is in the verse from Joshua, which preceded Solomon. The assumption is that this was included in G-d's commandment to appoint a king: a king must have authority. The book of Joshua contains the Jewish people saying so explicitly. Maimonides did not invent any laws; he just recorded them.

Comment: The building of the Temple was taken out of David's hands because he was a man of war, who fought many battles, although all of those battles were perfectly legitimate. Solomon reigned during a time of peace. The Malbim explains that G-d wanted the building of the Temple to not be motivated by temporary needs to strengthen the nation, and a wartime king could not afford to think that way. So G-d had Solomon build the Temple during a period of peace.

Comment: 1 - What verse in Joshua does it say that a king can kill his brother or anyone else for any reason - based on what? Whim? His brother wanted to marry Avishag. Why would that constitute a legitimate reason for killing him? 
2 - It says that under Solomon's reign there was peace. What exactly constitutes *peace* when people are being killed left, right and center?  Does killing through proxy keep ones hands clean of bloodshed?

Comment: @JSarai Why do you think Adonijah wanted to marry Avishag, David's quasi-widow? What would such an act have looked like to the populace?

Comment: @JoelK - Avishag the Shunamit was David's quasi-widow?? The Torah clearly states that he wasn't intimate with her, that she was there to keep him warm with her body heat, as one would employ for such things a puppy or hot water bottle. As to what *such an act* of marrying an unmarried woman would have *looked like to the populace*? I wasn't aware that this was about appearances and preserving honor. The woman was employed as a servant, wasn't legally bound to anyone, why would this cause an uproar - and if it could have - all Solomon could have said was NO and left it at that -without murder.

Comment: The verses are clear that Solomon took asking to marry Avishag as tantamount to requesting the kingship. Also see the end of the book of Samuel, where King David instructed Solomon to kill Shimi and Yoav before he died.

Comment: The verses were written by whom? Solomon had scribes, all they had to do was write down history as it unfolded from the perspective of the House of David. We now read this as if it came from Hashem Himself now and therefore all of the thoughts, feelings, sentiments and actions are sanctioned, pure, holy and virtuous? Please tell me because what I am understanding is that the Kings established a set of laws for themselves that counter Torah but then insert the name of Hashem here and there *Hashem blessed* Hashem spoke* and we consider this to be absolute truth.

Comment: If you won't accept the accuracy of the Bible I can't help you. You seem to have some animus towards Solomon where you are constantly attributing the worst of motives to him.

Comment: I am trying to understand how the Torah/Hashem sanctions killing, having numerous wives and marrying a Goya. Rabbis are always justifying this, logically and Halachically and I am just trying to understand. This is not a matter of *accuracy of the Bible*, but how to reconcile Halacha with the commentary of the life of Solomon.

Comment: Solomon is criticized for having too many wives and marrying the daughter of Pharoah. It could be said to be what led to his downfall. As to the killing, I have already explained it multiple times as the prerogative of the king.